# How to know that Minecraft Windows 10 (Windows Store) is maximized

Tags: c#, winapi, minecraft

I'm writing a program that records activity Minecraft Windows 10.

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
private static extern int DwmGetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int dwAttribute, out int pvAttribute, int cbAttribute);

const int DWMWA_CLOAKED = 14;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr minecraftPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        minecraftPtr = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Minecraft.Windows").First().Handle;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }

    #region
    int outAttr = 0;
    int hr = DwmGetWindowAttribute(minecraftPtr, (int)DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE.DWMWA_CLOAKED, out outAttr, sizeof(int));
    //string state = 0x0000000 != outAttr ? "Minecraft Visible" : "Minecraft is not Visible";
    listBox1.Items.Add((hr).ToString("X"));
    //listBox1.Items.Add(state);
    tbOutResult.Text += $"{outAttr} ";
    #endregion

    counter += System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Minecraft.Windows").Any() ? 1 : 0;

    tbTimesOf1000ms.Text = counter.ToString();
    tbMinutes.Text = (counter / 60).ToString("F1");
}
```

When Minecraft is running, the counter increments independently, it is minimized or not. The Method DwmGetWindowAttribute always returns 0 in argument outAttr.

int hr = ... returns 0.

What is the best way to solve my problem?

Comment: maybe look to see if an exception got thrown by GetProcessByName?

Comment: No. I added try construction to avoid an exception by .First() when target application is not running. For example, if app name change to Minecraft1.Windows DwmGetWindowAttribute returns 80070006.

Comment: Process handles are constant for the lifetime of the process, you don't need to retrieve it every time your timer ticks. And `GetProcessesByName` is somewhat expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, the main problem is to detect a full screen state, determining that my child is playing. This allows me to know how much time was spent playing. He can not play if the application is minimized

Comment: Are you sure `First().Handle` returns a window handle and not a process handle? `DwmGetWindowAttribute` expects a `HWND`.

Comment: "Only processes started through a call to Start set the Handle property of the corresponding Process instances."